# How to calculate the exponential function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions, exponential-function, exponential-sum

How to calculate the below equation

$$\ln \frac{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}+....+e^{x_n}}{n}$$

where $x_i, i=1...n$ and $n$ are some known values. In addition, $n=200$ and $x_i \in [1000, 2000]$. Or could we use some numerical ways to get the solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no shortcut for this. You have to do all the arithmetic. If you [edit] the question to tell us where this expression comes from and why you need it we may be able to suggest alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, I add more information and I believe it has a solution. Or could I calculate it on the computer?

Comment: If $M=\max\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$, then the answer lies between $M-\ln n$ and $M$. Since $\ln200\approx5.3$ and $1000\le M\le2000$, $M$ itself is a reasonable approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $x_1\geq x_2\geq \ldots \geq x_n$, I expect that resorting to well-known [log-sum-exp trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp) might provide an accurate answer:
\begin{align}
\ln (e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}+\ldots+e^{x_n})=x_1+\ln (1+e^{x_2-x_1}+\ldots+e^{x_n-x_1}).
\end{align}
The remaining thing is truncating the summation so as to strike a balance on the accuracy and the computational feasibility. I expect approximating it with
\begin{align}
x_1+\ln (1+e^{x_2-x_1}+\ldots+e^{x_m-x_1})
\end{align}
where $|x_m-x_1|\approx \text{(few tens)}$ will be quite good. In this case, the approximation error is just
\begin{align}
|\ln (1+e^{x_2-x_1}+\ldots+e^{x_n-x_1})-\ln (1+e^{x_2-x_1}+\ldots+e^{x_m-x_1})|&\leq e^{x_{m+1}-x_1}+\ldots+e^{x_n-x_1}\\
&\leq ne^{x_m-x_1}
\end{align}
For instance, if you let $|x_m-x_1|\approx -20$, the bound becomes $200 e^{-20}\approx 4.12\times 10^{-7}$.

Comment: Thank, Heedong, but how to incorporate the $n$ in this log-sum-exp equation？ There is a denominator $n$ in my equation.

Comment: Just subtract ln(n) from the result! ln(a/b)=ln(a)-ln(b).

Comment: Thanks, I got it!